# Submitting random string from an array, submits the string after echoed string

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Every time I click submit the name of the element I'm voting on changes to the element that shows up after the current echoed element when entered into the database. 
Any suggestions on how to fix this? I can't seem to figure it out.

Lets say the echo shows example2 on for the value in the form. I click example2 but example1 gets saved in the database. I'm not sure how to fix this. Thanks for the help.

Here's my code:

The array setup I'm using:

```
$array = array("example1","example2","example3");
$random = $array;
shuffle($random);

<?php echo array_pop($random);?>
```

PHP: Action

I'm using POST method in form.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("", "", "", "");
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_error . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
if (!$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO table(id, name, votes) VALUES (id, '".$random."', '".$votes."')")) {
    echo "Multi-INSERT failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
```

Comment: what you are trying to acheve? All i see here see is redundant codes.

Comment: when <?php echo array_pop($random);?> shows an element from the array and posts that element when clicked on and runs through the code a different element than the one clicked on is saved into the table. I want to make it the same element as the one clicked on. thanks. Sorry if i wasn't clear enough. what do you mean by "redundant codes"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your question clear, i believe you want the following:

- Pick up a random element from the array.
- Show it in a webpage.
- Insert it in database

So,

```
$array = array("example1","example2","example3");
shuffle($array);
$element = array_pop($array);    
echo $element;
```

Then insert the `$element` in database.

Above does what you wish. 
Rest of your code doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Got rid of the crazy code but your solution doesn't work when I echo the element  the name shows up but when I click on it in the HTML, it saves the name that comes after the current echoed element.

Comment: <form action="Voting_action.php" method="post">
          <td>
              <input type="submit" class="buttontable1" value="<?php echo($random);?>" name="name"/>
          </td>
             </form>

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!$stmt->bind_param("s", $id, $votes))
```

should be

```
if (!$stmt->bind_param("ss", $id, $votes)) because the number of strings and variables have to match.
```

Comment: Thanks for some constructive criticism. It didn't answer my initial question but you did spark and idea and I tested it out and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: well it didn't answer your question but you accepted it....? An accepted answer must give a solution to the question.